# col-xs-12 show that the content is at 100% width. but it only fit 50% of the page width

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem when my page goes into responsive. Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

[image]

Comment: Fits 50% because you have used "display: flex".

Comment: please add your code?

Answer (score 0):

It applies the col-sm-4, add also a col-lg-12 as I see (in your screenshot) you are using a wider screen.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question